# How is Fi's name pronounced?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I just met Fi in *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword*. How is her name pronounced?

Fee (like me)?

Fy (like my)?

Fih (like igloo)?

Or Matt (like at)?

Comment: I think the majority has more or less come down on the side of disallowing this sort of question, see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/are-pronunciation-questions-out-of-scope.  (Edit: Or maybe not, I see the Skyrim pronunciation question's been re-opened.)

Comment: In the Skyrim instance you cite, I would agree: off-topic In this case however, Fi's name is never spoken in game nor  mentioned in any auditory promotional materials. If I was asking how to pronounce Zelda or Link, then I would close the question myself.

Comment: I think this is a case in which the meta discussion needs to be re-visited. It's obvious their is still division in the community on this issue.

Comment: I do see your point, though I have an instinctual dislike of these questions.  They just seem too tangential to be "real" problems.  @Wipqozn Agreed, I've edited my answer there...

Comment: Also ... if it's never spoken, is this question answerable beyond a (possibly educated) guess?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Japanese spelling of Fi's name is **ファイ**, the romanization of which is **fai**. Therefore, the English pronunciation would be **faɪ** ([English IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA_for_English#Key)), as in rhyming with the word "my."  (You wrote this as "Fy".)

Comment: Interesting fact: The German name is “Phai” which further supports this pronounciation ;)

Comment: This is how the name is pronounced by the "Nintendo Week" hosts in the 12/8 episode on the Nintendo Channel in thier intro to the game.

Answer (score 1):

I heard that "Fi" is the shortened version of "**FI**eld guide", similar to Navi (short for **NAVI**gation) and Tatl & Tael (tattle tail). If that were the case, it would make sense for the pronunciation to be "Fee", which I think has a nicer ring to it that "Fai".